# linear transformation proof T:P2->P4

Tags: linear-algebra

can prove

$T(p(x)) = p(x+1)$ to be a Linear Transformation since there is preservation of vector addition

$T(p(x) + q(x)) = T((p+q)(x+1)) = p(x+1) + q(x+1)$

and scalar multiplication

$T(\alpha p(x)) = \alpha T(p(x))$

but I'm stumped with

$T: P2 \rightarrow P4 $
$T(p(x)) = (p(x+1))^2$

would appreciate any hints

So far,

$T(p(x) + q(x)) = T((p+q)(x+1))^2 = (p(x+1)+q(x+1))^2$

$= (p(x+1)+q(x+1))(p(x+1)+q(x+1))$

$= (p(x+1))^2+q(x+1)p(x+1)+p(x+1)q(x+1)+(q(x+1))^2$

$\neq  (p(x+1))^2 + (q(x+1))^2$

Comment: Is $T(cp)=cT(p)$?

Comment: What exactly is that last line that stumps you? You must show that $T$ preserves addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: Try some examples. Pick some *specific* quadratics $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, and check if $T(p + q)$ and $T(p) + T(q)$ are the same. If they're coming up the same, you could investigate why. If even one pair doesn't, then you have a counterexample.

Comment: @JohnDouma - question has been asked in a way that suggests LT is preserved but when I expand $(p(x+1))^2$ and $(q(x+1))^2$ I cant bring back to $T(p(x)) + T(q(x))$ so I suspect Im missing something.

Comment: @haz No matter how the question was posed, this is definitely not linear, and so trying to prove it is linear will inevitably fail. You should search for a counterexample.